# Spring boot - I want to write a POST endpoint to consume multipart/form-data WITHOUT any file uplload, I need to post json data as key-value pair pair

Tags: multipartform-data, key-value

I want to do something like this -

```java
@ApiOperation("Solve for tasks in JSON file")
@PostMapping(value = "/tasks/file", 
             consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, 
             produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Plan> solveTest(@RequestBody(value = "file") InputStream filrInputStream) {}
```

[image]

I tried adding jersey multipart dependency in my spring boot app and tried my api method signature as below, but when I try posting my json string I get input stream as empty-

```java
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
</dependency>  
    

    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(
                name = "file",
                dataType = "java.io.InputStream",
                examples = @io.swagger.annotations.Example(
                    value = {
                        @ExampleProperty(value = "[\r\n"
                                + "  {\r\n"
                                + "    \"duration\": 0,\r\n"
                                + "    \"xxxxxxTG\": \"string\",\r\n"
                                + "    \"sequence\": 0,\r\n"
                                + "    \"xxxxxx\": \"string\",\r\n"
                                + "    \"taskId\": \"string\",\r\n"
                                + "    \"taskType\": \"string\",\r\n"
                                + "    \"xcoordinate\": 0,\r\n"
                                + "    \"ycoordinate\": 0\r\n"
                                + "  }\r\n"
                                + "]", mediaType = "multipart/form-data")
                    })) 
        })
        @PostMapping(value = "/tasks/file", 
                        consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, 
                        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
                    )
        public ResponseEntity<Plan> solveTest1(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData)
```

Comment: Please provide what outcome you are looking for and please try to make an attempt first before making a post

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have made many attempts, same thing I am able to do in Jersey as well as in node service but not in spring boot. Basically the end result expected is to be able to post huge json data. By posting json data as value with key as "file"in request body, I am able to achieve the same in node service and  jersey framework. I am asking a question in this forum first time and not yet allowed to post screenshots, otherwise I could have also added pictures of my existing endpoints in node and Jersey.

Comment: Every time I try this in spring boot I get Unsupported Media type error. My code in Jersey uses @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream as the post method parameter. My swagger code in node looks like this -                                                    *    requestBody:
 *      required: true
 *      content:
 *        multipart/form-data:
 *          schema:
 *            type: object
 *            properties:
 *              file:
 *                $ref: '#/components/schemas/sampleRecord'